# Returning Table with null value causes error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I have a simple function that has optional parameters. When I leave out a parameter, which should just default to null, I get an error that it is not an integer.

Here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION rewrite(_postid integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
                                       _url character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE
            (
              PostTypeID                 integer,
              DestinationURL             varchar,
            )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$function$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
                SELECT 
                NULL AS PostTypeID,
                _url      AS DestinationURL,
                      
                FROM reference.destinations dest1
            
                WHERE length(TRIM(dest1.DestinationURL)) > 0
                AND _url LIKE '%' || TRIM(dest1.DestinationURL)) || '%'
                ORDER BY length(dest1.DestinationURL)) DESC
                LIMIT 1;
END;
$function$
```

If I run `SELECT * FROM utility.rewrite(_url := 'wikipedia.org')` then I get this error:

> [42804] ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
> Detail: Returned type text does not match expected type integer in
> column 1.

So `column1` must be the `PostTypeID` column in my `RETURNS TABLE` definition. But I am selecting `NULL AS PostTypeID` so why is it not just returning NULL?

If I run `SELECT * FROM utility.rewrite(_postid = 0, _url := 'wikipedia.org')` then it works fine. But I don't want `0` to be returned, I want NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you use the alias `posttypeid` in the query does not mean that PostgreSQL infers the data type of your PL/pgSQL variable.

Even though NULL can be any data type, PostgreSQL has to determine a data type for the result column of the query. Lacking other information, it arbitrarily chooses `text`.

Mapping the query result type to the function result type happens later, in PL/pgSQL. That is what causes the error you observe.

You can avoid the problem by specifying the type of NULL with an explicit type cast:

```
SELECT CAST (NULL AS integer)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense then for the `return table` definition to allow a null value in a column say like `PostTypeID integer default null`? Logically it makes no sense to cast a NULL as an integer. It is absurd.

Comment: I told you the cause of your problem and how to fix it. If you don't like the way PostgreSQL behaves, that's a different issue. You are welcome to improve it, as long as you don't break backward compatibility. Perhaps I spent too much time with SQL, but I see nothing weird about casting a value.

Comment: Its not that I don't like it how it behaves, I'm trying to understand how it makes sense to convert an unknown entity into an integer when the point of a NULL is that it is unknown?

Comment: Right, and after the cast it is an unknown integer.

Comment: Except you did  just that in your argument declaration; `_postid integer DEFAULT NULL::integer`. Change to `NULL::integer AS PostTypeID` and you will be matching the input.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver When I made the function I just typed `CREATE FUNCTION rewrite(_postid integer DEFAULT NULL, _url character varying DEFAULT NULL)` without any cast. I think my IDE (IntelliJ Idea/DataGrip) or maybe Postgresql itself added it automatically. I thought that `::` was obsolete and not proper SQL standard anymore?

Comment: It has never been standard SQL, it is PostgreSQL dialect.

Comment: Other option is to do: `SELECT _postid, _url ...`.  Then you would already have a `CAST` NULL. Also the aliases are not necessary, all that matters is that the query output columns match in number an type to the `RETURNS TABLE` declaration.